# Corona SDK - Splash screen for Android not full screen

Tags: android, coronasdk, game-engine, splash-screen

In my Corona SDK app, i have added all size of recommended splash screens.
http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html#launchimage

It is working perfectly on iOS devices (iPhone/iPad). But on android devices there is a black bar on top and bottom of splash screen. Anyone have idea how to fix it for Android devices? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read build.setting & config.lua API carefully there are so many options you can set.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so many different Android Screen sizes, the preferred method is to create a larger splash screen image with a bleed area at the edges. The image will be larger than (hopefully) all the different screen sizes, so that you don't get any black bars.

Comment: It is a universal app (iOS/Android). If i create Default.png of some size other than 320x480. Will Apple approve it?

Comment: Have you looked at this document: http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html#launch-images

Comment: This is the same document I have already mentioned link in question. I have placed all the 7 launch images. I am now planning to place new sizes when Android build is to prepared.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, if the width or height of the display is greater than 480 pixels, the larger image file(s) will be used.

Android displays all launch images in letterbox format, regardless of the scale setting in config.lua